# Validation loss and training loss curve , is that acceptable?

Tags: python, validation, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, training-data

I applying epilepsy seizure prediction using CNN. This is a plot for validation loss and training loss.
I don't know whether this curve is acceptable or not.

Any help would be appreciated
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's acceptable as long as increasing the number of epochs helps the validation loss to get lower beside there is no overfitting.